# EC2 Mongo connect timed out in AWS Lambda

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, clojure, aws-lambda

We have installed our Mongo db server in EC2 machine which is configured with a VPC and private subnet.

Then we are accessing the mongo from a AWS lambda function which is also configured with same VPC and subnet.

This setup is working, but randomly we are getting the following exception

```
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches 
WritableServerSelector.

Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, 
servers=[{address=mongodb.machine:27017,type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
 exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, 
 caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}}]
```

We are accessing the same Mongo from other web server which is inside EC2 machine, there we are not facing any issue. Both places we are using Clojure language with same library.

I don't know where the issue is because of Lambda or some thing else.

Has anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: I have. Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: we haven't found any solution for this. We planned to raise a AWS support ticket.

Comment: Did you? This is becoming quite a problem for me. :(

Comment: could you be exhausting the number connections? https://blog.cloudboost.io/i-wish-i-knew-how-to-use-mongodb-connection-in-aws-lambda-f91cd2694ae5

Comment: @pellyadolfo No of connections is not a problem, lambda was unable to reach mongo itself.

Comment: Did you found any solution? this same problem for me...